# How can I hide an HTML table that shares a class element with a table I want to keep visible?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that I am trying to hide. It is generated by from automatic HTML that I cannot edit. I know I can hide the class `table` however there are other tables on the page and throughout the site that use the same class. Are there any methods anyone can think of to hide just this table?

```
<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
```

Comment: Are there any other identifying classes/ids on this table that are unique to this table?

Comment: You can probably navigate to it from some element higher in the DOM.

Comment: If you can't slap an ID on it or another unique identifier, you will have to traverse the DOM.

Comment: Is it always the first table? last table? Is there anything else that identifies it or makes it unique, including html elements that might enclose it? Is using jQuery an option?

Comment: Do you have control over any of the html? E.g can you enclose the table in a div `<div id="targetDiv"><table class="table" /></div>`?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty :**

You could try to count how many .table you have :

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("table").length);
```

Determine which number equals the position of your div in your template :
manually... it should be constant, otherwise stop reading. ie :

```
var num = 15; //in example
```

Then hide the element you target :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("table")[num - 1].style.display = 'none'; //index begins at 0, so you must remove 1
```

But each time your template changes, you might need to recount every table. *An alternative would be (only if your table is the only one to have a 100% width), to select only the .table which has a 100% width.*

Answer (score 0):

You need a unique id on this table or a unique class.  The preferred way would be a unique css selector, `div .content .table`.  It is better to use a CSS selector like that instead having a ton of class or id's.

Answer (score -1):

Give the table that you want to hide a unique id.  Everything with the same class will be affected.   ID's are unique, so each can be modified separately.

```
<table id="hideMe" class="table" style="width:100%;">
```

Comment: Note that they **can not** change the markup of the table.